# Export Conda Environment with minimized requirements

Tags: python, anaconda, environment

The typical command to export a Anaconda environment to a YAML file is:

`conda env export --name my_env > myenv.yml`

However, one huge issue is the readbility of this file as it includes hard specifications for all of the libraries and all of their dependencies. Is there a way for Anaconda to export a list of the optimally smallest subset of commands that would subsume these dependencies to make the YAML more readable? For example, if all you installed in a conda environment was `pip` and `scipy`, is there a way for Anaconda to realize that the file should just read:

```
name: my_env
channels:
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - scipy=1.3.1
  - pip=19.2.3
```

That way, the anaconda environment will still have the exact same specification, if not an improved on (if an upstream bug is fixed) and anyone who looks at the yml file will understand what is "required" to run the code, in the sense that if they did want to/couldn't use the conda environment they would know what packages they needed to install?

Comment: Sometimes newer versions of packages that claim to be compatible aren't, or introduce bugs, or don't maintain exact reproducibility (if you care about that), etc -- which is why people frequently want their transitive dependencies pinned. Most package managers have both a dependencies file and a "lock file" -- the former is easier to read and update, the latter exact. Conda unfortunately doesn't yet have this built in. You might want to take a look at conda-lock as described here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/conda-dependency-management/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Options from the Conda CLI

This is sort of what the `--from-history` flag is for, but not exactly. Instead of including exact build info for each package, it will include only what are called **explicit specifications**, i.e., the specifications that a user has explicitly requested via the CLI (e.g., `conda install scipy=1.3.1`). Have a try:

```bash
conda env export --from-history --name my_env > myenv.yml
```

This will only include *versions* if the user originally included versions during installation. Hence, creating a new environment is very likely not going to use the exact same versions and builds. On the other hand, if the user originally included additional constraints beyond version and build they will also be included (e.g., a channel specification `conda install conda-forge::numpy` will lead to `conda-forge::numpy`).

Another option worth noting is the `--no-builds` flag, which will export every package in the YAML, but leave out the build specifiers. These flags work in a mutually exclusive manner.

---

### conda-minify

If this is not sufficient, then there is an external utility called [conda-minify](https://github.com/jamespreed/conda-minify) that offers some functionality to export an environment that is minimized based on a dependency tree rather than through the user's explicit specifications.

Comment: Nice! This is close to what I am talking about, and will probably work for my task. What I am looking for though is something that could consider the full set of installs and create a *minimal* conda env file, where regardless of how I got there, it only shows the minimum necessary library installs to reproduce the environment. E.g. if in my history I install `scikit-learn`, and then install `scipy`, I want it to ignore `scipy` because it is installed by the `sci-kit-learn` as a dependency.

Comment: @physincubus makes sense. You’d need to script that out - it’s not possible from current CLI. Perhaps there is a way to get only leaves of the dependency graph using Conda’s internal methods. Also, not sure how long-term you are hoping such minimal environments are supposed to be valid, but one concern is that dependencies evolve over time. I think you would need to include versions if you want to ensure that a given package will pull in a dependency that you exclude. Unfortunately, most users install without versions and `—from-history` will only include exact user specifications.

Comment: @physincubus just ran across this: https://github.com/jamespreed/conda-minify Sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: Oh snap this is perfect!

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [pipreqs](https://pypi.org/project/pipreqs/). It creates a requirements.txt file only based on the imports that you are explicitely doing inside your project (and you even have a `--no-pin` option to ignore the version numbers). You can later use this file to create a conda environemnt via `conda install --file requirements.txt`.

However, if you're aiming for an `evironments.yml` file you have to create it manually. But that's just copy and paste from the clean `requirements.txt`. You only have to separate conda from "pip-only" installs.

Comment: this is great advice, so I updooted, but not really what I am looking for. The reason conda environments has an advantage over pip requirements is because the environment solve is more complete. So when every package is specified they are identical, but like i allude to in my description if there is a bug fix in an upstream repo, conda will catch it but pip won't necessarily

Comment: Downvoted by original poster asked specifically about conda, not pip.  pip is not an environment manager.  Pip frequently corrupts conda environments because it does not re-verify the entire environment before proceeding.  Pip will downgrade dependencies of other packages and just install what was requested.  Pip does not re-verify environment-wide mutual package compatibility before dropping its load.  Conda verifies environment mutual package compatibility, presents it to users for verification (similar to a two-phase commit) before making the changes to the environment.

Answer (score 2):

See [new_conda_env](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/new_conda_env) another alternative for creating a new env file that only lists the user-installed packages (+ those appearing in .condarc) & without version numbers; only python has a version.