# Why does my evrionment.yaml have so many dependencies?

Tags: python, anaconda, yaml, virtualenv

I'm new to Anaconda and I have a project that needs `numpy` `matplotlib` and `pandas`. So I uninstalled all previous versions of python, installed anaconda, and created a new virtual environment for my project (and activated it). In there I ran the following commands:

```
conda install numpy -y

conda install matplotlib -y

conda install pandas -y
```

And when I ran `conda list`, I was able to find all of them. The problem is that there is also a ton of other dependencies that came with them.

Here is how the dependencies in my `environment.yaml` file looks:

```
dependencies:
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - ca-certificates=2020.7.22=0
  - certifi=2020.6.20=py37_0
  - cycler=0.10.0=py37_0
  - freetype=2.10.3=hd328e21_0
  - icu=58.2=ha925a31_3
  - intel-openmp=2020.2=254
  - jpeg=9b=hb83a4c4_2
  - kiwisolver=1.2.0=py37h74a9793_0
  - libpng=1.6.37=h2a8f88b_0
  - libtiff=4.1.0=h56a325e_1
  - lz4-c=1.9.2=hf4a77e7_3
  - matplotlib=3.3.1=0
  - matplotlib-base=3.3.1=py37hba9282a_0
  - mkl=2020.2=256
  - mkl-service=2.3.0=py37hb782905_0
  - mkl_fft=1.2.0=py37h45dec08_0
  - mkl_random=1.1.1=py37h47e9c7a_0
  - numpy=1.19.1=py37h5510c5b_0
  - numpy-base=1.19.1=py37ha3acd2a_0
  - olefile=0.46=py37_0
  - openssl=1.1.1h=he774522_0
  - pandas=1.1.3=py37ha925a31_0
  - pillow=7.2.0=py37hcc1f983_0
  - pip=20.2.3=py37_0
  - pyparsing=2.4.7=py_0
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py37h6538335_2
  - python=3.7.9=h60c2a47_0
  - python-dateutil=2.8.1=py_0
  - pytz=2020.1=py_0
  - qt=5.9.7=vc14h73c81de_0
  - setuptools=50.3.0=py37h9490d1a_1
  - sip=4.19.8=py37h6538335_0
  - six=1.15.0=py_0
  - sqlite=3.33.0=h2a8f88b_0
  - tk=8.6.10=he774522_0
  - tornado=6.0.4=py37he774522_1
  - vc=14.1=h0510ff6_4
  - vs2015_runtime=14.16.27012=hf0eaf9b_3
  - wheel=0.35.1=py_0
  - wincertstore=0.2=py37_0
  - xz=5.2.5=h62dcd97_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h62dcd97_4
  - zstd=1.4.5=h04227a9_0
```

Are all of these necessary? When I look at other people's environment.yaml files they always look so clean and don't have all these packages despite still having `numpy`, `matplotlib`, and `pandas`

Comment: That's normal. `numpy`, `matplotlib` and `pandas` have enormous dependency chains. If you're looking at other peoples' files and they don't have them, those people presumably aren't pinning transitive dependencies, but instead letting conda decide at installation time what versions to use. There are defensible reasons to do that, but there are also defensible reasons not to.

Comment: The only one that stands out to me is as not needed is tornado ... blas, intel-openmp, and mkl are "optional" in numpy, but they make it run faster

Comment: @CharlesDuffy and OneCricketeer, thanks for making it clear!

Comment: Sort of related, if you want to export a minimal `environment.yaml` file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64288844/570918

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll quote @Charles Duffy and @OneCricketeer in this answer:

@Charles Duffy:

> That's normal. numpy, matplotlib and pandas have enormous dependency chains. If you're looking at other peoples' files and they don't have them, those people presumably aren't pinning transitive dependencies, but instead letting conda decide at installation time what versions to use. There are defensible reasons to do that, but there are also defensible reasons not to.

@OneCricketeer:

> The only one that stands out to me is as not needed is tornado ... blas, intel-openmp, and mkl are "optional" in numpy, but they make it run faster