# How to list packages used in conda create/install command?

Tags: python, conda

Suppose I use the following command to make an environment called env1:

```
conda create -n env1 matplotlib numpy ipython jupyterlab
```

How can I at a later time get a simple listing showing '`matplotlib` `numpy` `ipython` `jupyterlab`'? I know about the `conda -list` command, but it shows something much more detailed (all dependencies, etc..) than what I want. I checked all the commands shown in [this documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/list.html) of conda's list command and none worked for me.

I understand that packages can also be installed using conda's `install` command, and expect those would be listed as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export Conda Environment with minimized requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284698/export-conda-environment-with-minimized-requirements) That is, the `conda list` command doesn't have this ability, but the `conda env export` command does via the `--from-history` flag.

Comment: You did `conda env export -n env1 --from-history`?

Comment: Thank you, @merv --> conda env export -n env1 --from-history  is exactly what I was looking for. I would mark this as an Answer if it was presented as one.

Comment: Glad to help. I would prefer to close this one to help minimize redundancy. But feel free to upvote my answer on the proposed duplicate.

Comment: I do not feel it is a duplicate as that page without your comment did not help me. I'm up marking all your comments since that's all I can do.

Comment: What did you find confusing about the other one? I.e., can I improve it in some way? The only difference I see in my other answer was that it includes a redirect from stdout to a file (`> env.yaml`).

Comment: You are right -- sorry, I overlooked your answer there and only did the command in the OP. I've now voted to close this as a duplicate and will go and upvote your answer there. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

try using `pipdeptree`. It shows you the dependency tree.

open your terminal
Install pipdeptree:`pip install pipdeptree` .go to your project directory and type `pipdeptree`.done.