# conda --from-history and --no-build doesn't work together

Tags: python, conda

I want to remove the build id when I'm creating `environment.yml` but also generate the file from history so there are less packages. However

```
 conda env export --no-build --from-history > environment.yml
```

still returns the build id for each package. Is there another way?

I am on latest 4.9.2 conda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Conda v4.9, **no, the two flags do not work together**. The `--from-history` flag will trigger only the explicit specifications being output, and those go down to whatever level of detail the user originally specified (can be versions, channels, builds, subdirs, etc.).

You may just need to strip it down after. E.g.,

```bash
conda env export --from-history | sed -E 's/(=[^=]+)=[^=]+$/\1/'
```

This should strip just the builds, but not the versions. However, it may miss some edge cases for the `pip:` section.

Alternatively, you may be interested in the related question, [Export Conda Environment with minimized requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64284698/570918), about exporting a minimized set of requirements (i.e., based on the dependency graph, rather than user history, which can still have redundancies).