# a minimal reproducible Conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, development-environment

Is there a way to create a reproducible conda environment (e.g. for a python project)?

Let's suppose we create a new environment from start:

```
conda create -n spiderman python=3.6
conda activate spiderman
conda env export > environment.yml
```

However, now the `environment.yml` file will contain dozens and dozens of packages as it records all of them.

Is there a way to minimalize this file, so that only parent packages are listed? E.g. when installing pandas, pandas packages are using NumPy under the hood and thus it is not necessary to list numpy in the  `environment.yml` file.

I am aware of the `pip-chill` concept and I am using it quite frequently. Still, I wanted to ask what are your best Ideas/tips

Comment: Listing all these packages _is_ necessary for a reproducible environment. Pandas does not depend on a single version of numpy, but rather a version range, so if numpy got updated you'd get a different environment the second time. Most package managers solve this by having two files, e.g. `package.json` and `yarn.lock` in yarn (JavaScript), `Cargo.toml` and `Cargo.lock` in cargo (Rust). In Python, Poetry does this as well, but I don't know how it relates to Conda.

Comment: reproducible is a key word here.  At a minimum, it will require full list of python packages + versions.  But runtime for e.g. numpy will also depend on pre-compiled binaries.  There is a tradeoff/spectrum between reproducibility and simplicity.  If you want full reproducibility, go with a docker image.  Mostly reproducible very simple: basic requirements.txt

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64284698/570918

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is

```
conda env export --from-history --name my_env > myenv.yml
```